# php constant can be referenced but defined() returns false

Tags: php, constants

Has anyone encountered this?

```
var_dump(CRYPT_SHA256 == 1); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(defined(CRYPT_SHA256)); // returns bool(false)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Add quotation marks**

```
defined('CRYPT_SHA256')
```

Otherwise, you are asking whether the *value* of the `CRYPT_SHA256` constant is also the name of another constant....

```
defined(CRYPT_SHA256) === defined('1');
```

***Edit :* Add namespace**

If your constant is defined in a namespace, you must include it in the constant name.

```php
namespace Some\Namespace;

const MY_CONST = 'value';

var_dump( defined('MY_CONST') ); // false unless another constant has been defined
var_dump( defined('Some\Namespace\MY_CONST'); // true
```

This is not the case in the original question, but it can be a cause of the same problem too.

Comment: Thank you - Making the L sign on my forehead

Comment: You are not alone, Dave. hehe And now that I see this answer, it dawns on me that this is *not* the first time I have made this mistake! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first statement also return false for me.

I have changed it a little bit, see below

```
define('CRYPT_SHA256',1);
  //var_dump(CRYPT_SHA256 == 1); // returns bool(true)
  var_dump('CRYPT_SHA256');
var_dump(defined('CRYPT_SHA256')); // returns bool(false)
```